Java regular expression for multiple matchers
I'm trying to build a regular expression to return initial value and then all key value pairs.
Text is
abcd{123}hello world{456}asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd{678}asd aaasddd

Expected output is
    HEADER -> abcd
    123 -> hello world
    456 -> asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd
    678 -> asd aaasddd

Thanks in advance...
I tried with below regex but it does not provide correct results
(?:{\d{4}})([\w]+[\S]*[.,]*[\s]+)


bit confusing: in example you have 3 digit numbers, but in regex you use \d{4}, that is, 4 digits?!? Also just an example is not the best description...

You can use:
([^\\{\\r\\n]+)?\\{\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\}([^\\{\\r\\n]+)

Code:

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abcd{123}hello world{456}asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd{678}asd aaasddd";

        String p = "([^\\{\\r\\n]+)?\\{\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\}([^\\{\\r\\n]+)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String header = matcher.group(1);
            String key = matcher.group(2);
            String value = matcher.group(3);

            if (header != null) {
                System.out.println("HEADER -> " + header);
            }
            System.out.println(key + " -> " + value.trim());
        }
    }
}



Prints
HEADER -> abcd
123 -> hello world
456 -> asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd
678 -> asd aaasddd


Notes:

([^{\r\n]+)?: capture group 1 for the HEADER (and being optional ?).
({\d+}): capture group 2 for the numbers.
([^{\r\n]+): capture group 3 for the values.


Thanks for the quick answer. This work perfectly except the HEADER portion. Header also could be any characters. E.g.
.....01.FTI0350 .FTR811XFT811  {123}hello world
Kindly modify your regex to capture this

@wasankawickramasinghe Try ([^\{\r\n]+)?\{\s*(\d+)\s*\}([^\{\r\n]+)?

If the header and all the values should contain at least a single non whitespace character, and assuming that the only curly's you are matching are surrounded by digits:
(?:^\h*+(?!.*}\h*(?:\{|$))([^{}\r\n]+)|\G(?!^))\{(\d+)}([^{}\r\n]+)

The pattern matches:

(?: Non capture group

^ Start of string
\h*+ Match optional leading horizontal whitespace chars with a possessive quantifier
(?!.*}\h*(?:\{|$)) Assert that to the right there are not only horizontal whitespace chars after } till either the next { or the end of the string
([^{}\r\n]+) Capture group 1, match 1+ chars other than the listed in the negated character class
| Or
\G(?!^) Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string


) Close the non capture group
\{(\d+)} Capture 1+ digits between curly's in group 2
([^{}\r\n]+) Capture group 3, match 1+ chars other than { and }

See a regex demo and a Java demo
Example in Java:
String regex = "(?:^\\h*+(?!.*\\}\\h*(?:\\{|$))([^\\{\\}\\r\\n]+)|\\G(?!^))\\{(\\d+)\\}([^\\{\\}\\r\\n]+)";
String string = "abcd{123}hello world{456}asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd{678}asd aaasddd";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.printf("HEADER -> %s%n", m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", m.group(2), m.group(3));
}

Output
HEADER -> abcd
123 -> hello world
456 -> asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd
678 -> asd aaasddd


Regex can be used to perform some amazing text transformations, as demonstrated by the other answers (and accepted). However, if you work in team, spare a thought for the next person to edit your code. Some might be less happy to apply upgrades to:
([^\\{\\r\\n]+)?\\{\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\}([^\\{\\r\\n]+)
(?:^\h*+(?!.*}\h*(?:\{|$))([^{}\r\n]+)|\G(?!^))\{(\d+)}([^{}\r\n]+)

You've shown a really simple format which is much like CSV but with alternating delimiters:
String line = "abcd{123}hello world{456}asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd{678}asd aaasddd";

There are several easier ways to extract the text - even by using String.indexOf. Here are some suggestions which pulls out your fields in one/two lines:
String[] fields = line.split("[\\{\\}]");

Example access:
System.out.println("HEADER -> "+fields[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i+=2) {
    System.out.println(fields[i]+" -> "+fields[i+1]);
}

Alternative:
String[] fields = line.split("\\{");

System.out.println("HEADER -> "+fields[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
    String[] kv = fields[i].split("\\}");
    System.out.println(kv[0]+" -> "+kv[1]);
}

Output
HEADER -> abcd
123 -> hello world
456 -> asd * ~ . , 1243214 aadasd
678 -> asd aaasddd

Clearly, these suggestions might not deal with punctuation and validation for cases, but are easier to maintain.
